# Which is the most acceptable numeral for 1980 to 1989?

Tags: numerals

Previously, I asked a question about whether I should omit the article, "the" before the late 80s.

I saw in the answer by Absolute Beginner that he writes '80s for Eighties, the apostrophe is added before the numeral, i.e. 80s. Lawrence C put the apostrophe in between, i.e. 80's.

The answers have made me very confused, could you tell me which is the correct numeral for the years 1980, 1981, 1982... 1989:

> 80's, or '80s, or 80s ?

I always write 80s, does it mean that I am wrong?

Please help!

Comment: Use 80's if it's possessive. Use 80s (or '80s) if not. It's largely a matter of style. A preceding apostrophe indicates that "19" has been omitted. Using '80's for the possessive would be confusing, however, so it isn't recommended).

Comment: [And it is stated that *The New Yorker*, “that famously punctilious periodical,” renders “the nineteen-eighties” as the “1980’s,” which it does not. *The New Yorker* renders “the nineteen-eighties” as “the nineteen-eighties.”](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2004/06/28/bad-comma)

Comment: When the shortened form of 80s created questions, write in its original form then. Now, there is only one answer left: 1980s. It's definitely not 1980's.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The `'` in `'80s` is a placeholder for the omitted `19` in `1980s`. For most people those are the only '80s relevant to their personal experience, so it is safe to omit the century.

It works in the same way as in `don't` for `do not` and `it's` for `it is`.

In my opinion, just writing `80s` is fine, too.

Writing `1980's` in this context <strike>is just plain wrong!</strike> feels wrong to me. As Larry Trask points out in his [*Guide to Punctuation*](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/plurals), it is commonly used at least in American English.

In my opinion it would only be correct, if you wanted to describe a [possessive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive). For something that "belongs to" `1980`: So, "[Hurricane Allen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Allen) was 1980's first named hurricane" would be fine. It was the first named hurricane of the 1980 season. (Note, that this refers only to the year 1980, not the decade 1980s!)

So the wide use of both versions on the internet (just use your favourite search engine to find thousands of sites where `80's` is used) propably is due to the differences in American and British English usage.

Comment: Thanks Alexander Kosubek. Is the apostrophe also a placeholder for 1880s or 1780s or 1680s?

Comment: In what way is a pattern that is used by many native speakers (using an apostrophe between a year and a pluralising s) "just plain wrong". The orthography of English is defined by its users, and if both 80s and 80's are used, neither is incorrect. I tend to use 80s, but I would not describe those members of my language community who use 80's as wrong.

Comment: In my youth the apostrophe was obligatory with plurals of letters and numbers. Most publishers and academic style guides have now dropped this convention, and I'm glad to see it go; but it cannot be said to be "wrong".

Comment: Just remember that if you are in a setting where timelessness is expected (i.e. a scientific publication) you are expected to mention the century, even if it is obvious. In a less formal environment, it is fine though.

Comment: there is exactly one person known to have been born before 1900, and she was born in 1899. There aren't many people talking today for whom any other '80s are relevant!

Comment: @njzk2 Huh?  What about [Columbus](https://g.co/kgs/zdV34K)?  Or are you talking about people still alive?  What @ Mindwin is saying is that a scientific publication talking about '44 (1944)  could be misunderstood in not too many years to mean 2044.  Timelessness requires that you write the full four digit year for clarity.

Comment: @cullub, yes, when I say "there is exactly one person known to have been born before 1900", I don't mean in the entirety of history, I mean alive today.

Comment: I love when people say that use of a phrase by native speakers is "just plain wrong."  It's always funny.  That being said, if I had to venture a guess as to why 80's became a common notation it would be because "5" and "s" look so similar.  The apostrophe provides some separation which may help at a reading comprehension level.  The apostrophe was probably unconsciously selected because 's is such a common pattern that we were comfortable with it.

Comment: "The 1980s' music is the best" is correct, but "80s music is the best" is more natural.

Comment: @StoneyB I apologize for what seems to have been too harsh a rejection. In hindsight it is probably due to my native German language that I took what [Larry Trask in his _Guide to Punctuation_](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/apostrophe/plurals) calls _unusual_ for _wrong_ for decades. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @JamesK As I already answered to StoneyB, I just updated my answer, including a source regarding use of apostrophes with plural-s in numbers. - I also changed what in my mind was intended as an expression of opinion ("plain wrong") to a more appropriate wording for a site that is supposed to give definitive answers.

Comment: Would you say then that "'80s" tends to be used for "1980s", as the 1980's recent history makes it most closely associated with the '80s placeholder, when compared to the 1880s for example?

Answer (score 10):

The apostrophe in `'80s` marks the omission of the century, just like an apostrophe in a contraction shows the omission letters.

The apostrophe in `80's` comes from an old style rule for making plurals of numerals and letters (`mind your p's and q's`).  This style rule has fallen out of fashion, but it was common enough that you'll still sometimes see it.

The most common correct answer nowadays would be `'80s`.  Some might not bother with an apostrophe at all and just write `80s`, but that would be less precise.

Technically, `'80's` would also be considered correct by adherents to the old style rule, but that could lead absurd constructions like, `The '80's' biggest pop star was Michael Jackson.`.

Comment: Not merely absurd but with typewriter apostrophes ambiguous: you can't tell what's an apostrophe and what's single quotes. :)

Comment: Technically your last one should be `The 80s' biggest pop star` to cover the 80s, `80's` with the apostrophe before the `s` would technically be something belonging to `80` alone

Comment: @user568458:  Read what I wrote again.  There are three apostrophes in that example:  one for the elided century, one of the old style rule for making plurals of numerals and letters, and one after the _s_ to make those years possessive.

Answer (score 1):

From a strictly logical standpoint, `'80s` makes the most sense, using the apostrophe to mark the omission of the `19`, followed by `80s` as a further abbreviation that omits the apostrophe. However, I've seen `80's` probably more than anything else, and very rarely see `'80s`.

Bottom line: In most contexts, you're good with either `80s` or `80's`, as long as you're consistent. If you're writing in a formal context (academic or professional) there will be a style guide to tell you which to use.

Comment: Just because you've seen it, doesn't make it right. 80's is definitely wrong. '80s is the most correct. The reason for this is explained in detail in the other answers to the question. Although the OP's title asks which is the most appropriate, the body of his question asks which is the most correct.

Comment: @flith Prescriptivist much? Language is about consensus - the only "wrong" answer is one that an average native speaker would consider to be wrong. Especially in an ELL context, it's important to distinguish between "that's wrong, no one would ever say that" and "this structure is inappropriate for setting X but you see it all the time in casual contexts."